# Delete values in line based on column index using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I want to be able to delete the values to the RIGHT(starting from given column index) from the `test.txt` at the given column index based on a given length, `N`.

Column index refers to the position when you open the file in the VIM editor in LINUX.

If my `test.txt` contains `1234 5678`, and I call my `delete_var` function which takes in the `column number` as 2 to start deleting from and `length N` as 2 to delete as input, the `test.txt` would reflect `14 5678` as it deleted the values from column 2 to column 4 as the length to delete was 2.

I have the following code as of now but I am unable to understand what I would put in the `sed` command.

```
delete_var() {

    sed -i -r 's/not sure what goes here' test.txt
}

clmn_index= $1
_N=$2

delete_var "$clmn_index" "$_N"   # call the method with the column index and length to delete
```

```
#sample test.txt (before call to fn)
1234 5678
```

```
#sample test.txt (after call to fn)
14 5678
```

Can someone guide me?

Comment: with column you mean bytes? you can use string manipulation for example ${var:3:6}

Comment: Can you please your sample input with expected output?

Comment: @alecxs I mean column index in the file when we open it in LINUX vim editor

Comment: So you want to remove second and third letter? Like `cut --complement -c2,3`? A "column" is usually something that belong in a table - columns are logically separated, by a comma or a tab between columns. A line of text just has characters.

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, I want to remove it like that and write those changes back to the same test.txt file.The column index is when like you can be in row 1 in a file in linux VIM editor and move side ways and that increases the column index. I agree it also refers to the char position in the line

Comment: @anubhava I just updated the questions

Comment: yes! you want explicitly sed?

Comment: @alecxs I thought sed would be easiest, I am really new to this and if you have any easier solution, share it please

Comment: @KamilCuk seems to have easiest solution where you can calculate byte offsets with arithmetic expansion `$(($1 - 1))`, `$(($1 + $2 - 1))`

Comment: @Anna why did you delete [this mornings question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62876819/1745001) that I answered in a comment after it got re-opened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid using regex for this task. It is easier to get this done in `awk` with simple `substr` function calls:

```
awk -v i=2 -v n=2 'i>0{$0 = substr($0, 1, i-1) substr($0, i+n)} 1' file
```

```
14 5678
```

Comment: its inside function use i=$1 n=$2

Comment: Yes that right @alecxs. These hard coded values are used as an example only. OP can use `$1, $2` there.

Comment: Thank you :) .Appreciate it

Comment: If you have gnu awk then use: `awk -i inplace -v i=2 -v n=2 'i>0{$0 = substr($0, 1, i-1) substr($0, i+n)} 1' file`

Answer (score 2):

Assumping OP **must** use `sed` (otherwise other options could include `cut` and `awk` but would require some extra file IOs to **replace** the original file with the modified results) ...

---

Starting with the `sed` command to remove the 2 characters starting in column 2:

```
$ echo '1234 5678' > test.txt
$ sed -i -r "s/(.{1}).{2}(.*$)/\1\2/g" test.txt
$ cat test.txt
14 5678
```

Where:

- `(.{1})` - match first character in line and store in buffer #1
- `.{2}` - match next 2 characters but don't store in buffer
- `(.*$)` - match rest of line and store in buffer #2
- `\1\2` - output contents of buffers #1 and #2

Now, how to get variables for `start` and `length` into the `sed` command?

Assume we have the following variables:

```
$ s=2     # start
$ n=2     # length
```

To map these variables into our `sed` command we can break the `sed` search-replace pattern into parts, replacing the first `1` and `2` with our variables like such:

- replace `{1}` with `{$((s-1))}`
- replace `{2}` with `{${n}}`

Bringing this all together gives us:

```
$ s=2
$ n=2
$ echo '1234 5678' > test.txt

$ set -x          # echo what sed sees to verify the correct mappings:
$ sed -i -r "s/(.{"$((s-1))"}).{${n}}(.*$)/\1\2/g" test.txt
+ sed -i -r 's/(.{1}).{2}(.*$)/\1\2/g' test.txt

$ set +x
$ cat test.txt
14 5678
```

Alternatively, do the subtraction (`s-1`) before the `sed` call and just pass in the new variable, eg:

```
$ x=$((s-1))
$ sed -i -r "s/(.{${x}}).{${n}}(.*$)/\1\2/g" test.txt
$ cat test.txt
14 5678
```

Comment: does replace all occurences in test.txt (OP did not clarify how to specify line no)

Comment: @alecxs correct, then again, the OP hasn't provided any details suggesting that a) there is more than 1 line and/or 2) if more than one line then which line to process; not nitpicking ... just working with what the OP provided (so far)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like:

```
cut --complement -c $1-$(($1 + $2 - 1))
```

Should just work and delete columns between `$1` and `$2` columns behind it.

> please provide code how to change test.txt

`cut` can't modify in place. So either pipe to a temporary file or use `sponge`.

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
cut --complement -c $1-$(($1 + $2 - 1)) test.txt > "$tmp"
mv "$tmp" test.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

One idea using `cut`, keeping in mind that storing the results back into the original file will require an intermediate file (eg, `tmp.txt`) ...

---

Assume our variables:

```
$ s=2          # start position
$ n=2          # length of string to remove
$ x=$((s-1))   # last column to keep before the deleted characters (1 in this case)
$ y=$((s+n))   # start of first column to keep after the deleted characters (4 in this case)
```

At this point we can use `cut -c` to designate the columns to keep:

```
$ echo '1234 5678' > test.txt

$ set -x              # display the cut command with variables expanded
$ cut -c1-${x},${y}- test.txt 
+ cut -c1-1,4- test.txt
14 5678
```

Where:

- `1-${x}` - keep range of characters from position 1 to position $(x) (1-1 in this case)
- `${y}-` - keep range of characters from position ${y} to end of line (4-EOL in this case)

**NOTE**: You could also use `cut`'s ability to work with the complement (ie, explicitly tell what characters to remove ... as opposed to above which says what characters to keep). See KamilCuk's answer for an example.

Obviously (?) the above does not overwrite `test.txt` so you'd need an extra step, eg:

```
$ echo '1234 5678' > test.txt
$ cut -c1-${x},${y}- test.txt > tmp.txt    # store result in intermediate file
$ cat tmp.txt > test.txt                   # copy intermediate file over original file
$ cat test.txt
14 5678
```

Comment: @alecxs - yes, the actual `cut` operation doesn't require the `tmp.txt` file **but** OP has also asked to overwrite the original file ... and I'm hesitant to do something like `cut ... infile > infile` hence the use of the intermediate `tmp.txt` file; if you've got a way to apply the `cut` **and** overwrite the original file, without using a temp file, I'm all ears! :-)

Comment: yes, no, maybe; for a single line file, probably; for a larger file, with buffering by the pipe you could run into a race condition where you either feed your output into your input, or you truncate the input

Answer (score 1):

Below command result in the elimination of the 2nd character. Try to use this in a loop

```
sed s/.//2 test.txt
```